# How to design a factory that creates generic classes with upper bounded parameters from a string token

Tags: scala, generics, types, playframework, slick

I am trying to develop an automatic REST CRUD using Slick.

The behaviour is the following. If I call `GET /events`, I would like to get information about the token `events` (I mean, get the model, the type of the primary key and the table definition).

I am stuck, when I try to write the factory that creates generic classes with upper bounded parameters.

I want my factory to create `DaoService` :

```
trait Entity


// `Table` is defined in Slick
abstract class PKTable[E, PK](tag: Tag, tableName: String) extends Table[E](tag, tableName){
  def id: Rep[PK]
}


// `BaseColumnType` is necessary to compare ids in the `find` method
// `Expect` is a custom `Either`
class DaoService[E <: Entity, PK <: BaseColumnType[PK], V <: PKTable[E, PK]] {

  def findAll(tableQuery: TableQuery[V]): Future[Expect[Seq[E]]] =
    dao.runForAll(tableQuery)


  def find(tableQuery: TableQuery[V], id: PK): Future[Expect[Option[E]]] =
    dao.runForHeadOption(tableQuery.filter(_.id === id))

// ....

}
```

My factory looks like :

```
class Factory @Inject()(dao: Dao){

    def create(token: String): Option[DaoService[_, _, _]] = token match {
      case "events" => Some(new DaoService[Event, UUID, EventTableDef](dao))
      case _        => None
    }

}
```

But I get this error :

```
[error] test.scala:30: type arguments [Event,UUID,EventTableDef] do not conform to class DaoService's type parameter bounds [E <: Entity,PK <: BaseColumnType[PK],V <: PKTable[E,PK]]
[error]       case "events" => Some(new DaoService[Event, UUID, EventTableDef](dao))
[error]                        ^
```

I have tried a lot solutions but nothing works. I don't understand why types are not inferred. Do have any idea to fix my problem ?

Comment: A way to fix this problem is with a cast (`.asInstanceOf[Option[DaoService[_, _, _]]]`). But it's ugly. If you have another solution, please, let me know.